# Radio-to-slider in modal body don't display correctly

Tags: css, radio-button, bootstrap-modal

I am using radios-to-slider plugin.

When the modal is shown the slider is not displayed correctly

**Error:**

[image: error]

But If I re-size window manually and restore it to normal everything is in the perfect place.

**Perfect:**

[image: perfect]

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal1">Open Modal</a>
<div class="modal fade customModal" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: none;">
                <div class="panel-heading bg-color-1 border-color-1">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form action="#" method="POST" role="form" id="form1">
                        <label for="cbOptions">Select</label>
                        <div class="form-group formField">
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker"id="cbOptions" required></select>
                        </div>

                        <label>Slider</label>
                        <div class="form-group formField">
                            <div data-toggle="buttons">
                                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" class="opciones" data-style="android" data-on="8" data-off="8" data-onstyle="info">
                                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" class="opciones" data-style="android" data-on="9" data-off="9" data-onstyle="info">
                                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" class="opciones" data-style="android" data-on="10" data-off="10" data-onstyle="info">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="radios">
                            <input id="option1" name="options" type="radio">
                            <label for="option1">8</label>
                            <input id="option2" name="options" type="radio">
                            <label for="option2">9</label>
                            <input id="option3" name="options" type="radio">
                            <label for="option3">10</label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Radios to slider CSS](https://github.com/rubentd/radios-to-slider/blob/master/css/radios-to-slider.min.css)
      [Radios to slider JS](https://github.com/rubentd/radios-to-slider/blob/master/js/jquery.radios-to-slider.js)

Example Error: [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/mariopin138/pen/gvLLrg)
Example Fix  : [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/mariopin138/pen/aqpZVm)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @GibinEalias html code?

Comment: Yes, HTML, CSS, JS or whatever is relevant to find a solution to your question.

Comment: @GibinEalias I use bootstrap v3.3.5 and radios-to-slider v0.3.2 css files

Comment: Can you share a codepen link? I tried with one - https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/rJWMMY but its no where matching to your scenario.

Comment: @GibinEalias Try this one - [link](https://codepen.io/mariopin138/pen/gvLLrg)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**  Radios to slider needs a function to initialize radio buttons. I put this function inside the shown modal event and now the slider is shown correctly.

Sorry for my bad english.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#radios').radiosToSlider();
});
```

Comment: Up-voting as you have found the answer. You shall update your codepen link with the solution.